# How to partial update multiple documents at once in solr?

Tags: solr

I have the following command which I was expecting to work

```
curl http://localhost/solr/collection1/update?commit=true -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
  {
    "meta.something": "78c93c7d-2a9d-4cee-8cbc-1a8bba544678",
    "meta.type": "newsletter",
    "meta.type": { "set": "report" }
  }
]'
```

But it fails with

> "error":{"msg":"Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: _id","code":400}}

So it seems it is not possible to do this without specifying the primary key. But is there some way I can update everything that matches that criteria with some script or something?

Comment: you need to pass the uniqueKey of the solr document...The update wont work without it